# What is the preferred mechanism to use icons with button labels

Tags: html, user-interface, usability

I have seen the following snippet of UI code to use icons with labels

```
<a href="">
    <img alt src="img/save.gif" class="icon">
    <span>Save</span>
</a>
```

OR

would it make sense to make combine this into a single entity (i.e. image icon plus the label).

My concern is if we choose a different theme (color scheme), then I will not be able to use different colors for my labels and might have to regenerate the image. Using the first approach gives me the flexibility to do so.

Comment: I believe you've given your own answer already, if this approach gives you the most flexibility use this.

Comment: am not sure on the right practice and hence this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know about the layout or the colors you are using but the following are my points:

1. Relative alignment between the image and the text can be difficult to acheive (with my basic HTML/CSS knowledge) when you have the two separately
2. You cay that you prefer to have them separate because you want the possibility to change the color of text during "color scheme changes". But are you sure you dont want to change the images as well (another set of icons)? You might have the same problem of color mismatches. (You might choose the icons in such a manner that they "go along" with all the color schemes of your site, then again you can choose the color of your labels in the same menner).

Again, I am not sure of the layout/colors you are choosing, so the definitive answer is (as always) "depends on your site"

Comment: am not sure if I would want to change the icon colors here, as you mention it just compounds the problem and for every theme, i should dynamically change the image with some kind of a naming convention and load the appropriate image.

I am not sure if this is worth the hassle, am looking for best practices here

Answer (score 0):

Consider hyperlink cues for common link icons.  For example:

html

```
<a href="files/holidays.pdf">View Holidays</a>
```

CSS

```
a[href $='.pdf'] { 
       padding-right: 18px;
       background: transparent url(icon_pdf.gif) no-repeat center right;
    }
```

Styling of each can be handled in CSS.  Works for just about every file type extension out there.  This might not work for your specific example (would have to see the larger context) but it's a great trick for download links, etc.

Comment: I am looking to use the approach (i.e. separating icon and the label) for commonly used icons related to CRUD (e.g. Save, Delete, Update, Cancel ...)